# SVG fill-in/drawing animation

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I, using an SVG, javascript and HTML5 only (not video), make an animation on a web page that looks like the animation is being filled in, e.g. the lines extending from the initial point through each vertex, and the shapes being filled from say the top-left to the bottom-right?

I know I can use background color shapes and animate them moving through complex paths in layers to gradually unhide the shapes and lines, but is there no easier way than this? A jQuery effects script, CSS3, SVG animation library, there must be something...?

Comment: This is a great job for Canvas - it's what it's made for: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/learning-basics-html5-canvas

Comment: Thanks, that's true, but I think Canvas capability goes way beyond that, plus not sure breadth of user-agents have comparably stable implementations. Good idea.